# Login as root to shell through java

Tags: java, shell

Through my java program, I am able to login to the shell and execute cmds.
To login I provide Hostname, username, password, port.

My problem is I then need to change to root user only by issuing the su command (to login as root) and then at Password prompt provide rootpassword as below.

```
support@mygateway:/tmp$ su
Password:


BusyBox v1.17.3 (2020-10-08 06:33:26 CEST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

root@mygateway:~#
```

I am able to successfully create a SSHShell and execute cmds without root access using the below methods(already available). But how do I login with root access?

```
/**
 * Creates the SSHShell
 */
private SSHShellConnectionManager(String host, int port, String userName, String password)
        throws JSchException, IOException {
    Closure expectClosure = getExpectClosure();
    for (String linuxPromptPattern : new String[] { "\\>", "#", "~#", "~\\$",">"}) {
        try {
            Match match = new RegExpMatch(linuxPromptPattern, expectClosure);
            linuxPromptMatches.add(match);
        } catch (MalformedPatternException malformedEx) {
            throw new RuntimeException(malformedEx);
        }
    }
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    this.session = jsch.getSession(userName, host, port);
    session.setPassword(password);
    Hashtable<String, String> config = new Hashtable<>();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect(60000);
    this.channel = (ChannelShell) session.openChannel("shell");
    //this.expect = new Expect4j(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getOutputStream());
    this.expect = new Expect4j(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getOutputStream());
    channel.connect();
}

/**
 * Executes a command on the remote host.
 *
 * @param command
 *            the command to be executed
 * @param getExitStatus
 *            return the exit status captured in the stdout
 * @param withErr
 *            capture the stderr as part of the output
 * @return the content of the remote output from executing the command
 * @throws Exception
 *             exception thrown
 */
public String executeCommand(String command, Boolean getExitStatus, Boolean withErr) throws Exception {
    String result = "";
    String resultErr = "";

    Channel channel = this.session.openChannel("exec");
    System.out.println("COMMAND TO EXECUTE ON ROUTER " + command);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
    InputStream commandOutput = channel.getInputStream();
    InputStream commandErr = ((ChannelExec) channel).getErrStream();
    channel.connect();
    byte[] tmp = new byte[4096];
    while (true) {
        while (commandOutput.available() > 0) {
            int i = commandOutput.read(tmp, 0, 4096);
            if (i < 0) {
                break;
            }
            result += new String(tmp, 0, i);
        }
        while (commandErr.available() > 0) {
            int i = commandErr.read(tmp, 0, 4096);
            if (i < 0) {
                break;
            }
            resultErr += new String(tmp, 0, i);
        }
        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            if (commandOutput.available() > 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (getExitStatus) {
                result += "exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus();
                if (withErr) {
                    result += "\n With error:\n" + resultErr;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
        }
    }
    channel.disconnect();
    System.out.println("COMMAND RESPONSE :" + result);
    return result;
}



/**
 * Closes shell.
 */
public void close() {
    if (expect != null) {
        expect.close();
    }
    if (channel != null) {
        channel.disconnect();
    }
    if (session != null) {
        session.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you run your code as root user?.

Comment: No, cant do so. I require the code to follow this login procedure into shell, first as normal login and then switch to root user.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Channel channel = this.session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("su <<!"); // updated this line
channel.setInputStream(null);
OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
channel.connect();
out.write((password + "\n!\n").getBytes()); // updated this line
out.flush();
```

Comment: Sean, Unfortunately, sudo is not available at that level. Only once I get into root access sudo command is available.

Comment: @DivyaBhalla OK, I modified my answer to use su instead of sudo.  However I didn't test any of it.  I got the idea from https://askubuntu.com/questions/354838/is-there-a-single-line-command-to-do-su